# Precalculus Trig Problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have no clue where to start this problem, some help would be awesome and much appreciated!

> $$\text{If }\sin(x)-\cos(x)=-0.3, \text{ evaluate }\sin(2x).$$

Answer (score 6):

Note that
$$(\sin(x) - \cos(x))^2 = \sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) - 2 \sin(x) \cos(x) = 1 - \sin(2x)$$
Now use this to compute what you want.